# Page id without '?' in URL

Tags: php, database, variables, url-routing

I have seen some websites where different pages are accessed via a page id which isn't passed through via the get method..

So something like this:
http://www.website.com/sitefolder/pageid/
Where as often at other websites I see:
http://www.website.com/index.php?id=12

I know that the different pages of example 1 are stored in a db and not in different folders as it would suggest..

Normally if you have a forward slash this would mean you're going through different folders..

Can somebody explain me how I can create the forward slash page id indicator without havering to make hundreds of different folders for the different pages?

So just simply one php page in the 'sitefolder' which adapts its content by the page id or page name or URL alias passed through the URL without using the '?id=12' method.

Comment: Search for "URL rewriting" and ["mod_rewrite"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: You are looking for `Rewrite rules`, if you are using Apache you want mod_rewrite

Comment: There are many many questions here with common examples. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess  Other examples and tutorials are likely called things like "pretty URLs" or "clean URLs"

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this using a `.htaccess` rule with `mod_rewrite` enabled, like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)$  index.php?id=$1
```

This would rewrite `example.com/12` to `example.com/index.php?id=12`.

**Edit**: The RegEx, broken down:

- `^` Match start of line
- `/` Match slash
- `([^/]+)` Match and save the
  first group of characters that aren't a slash
- `$` Match end of line

And in the case of a `RewriteRule` RegEx, the "line" means anything after `example.com`.

Comment: Thanks! 
I will definitely have a look into that.
could you please explain a bit more about the ^/([^/]+)$ part?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right that usually "/" means going to next folder .. but sometime you may also customize the url structure as per your needs ....

You need to enable url rewritting for this .
This can be accomplished using .htaccess rules like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)(/([^/.]+))?(/([^/.]+))?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

or you can have your own customised mvc and in such case you can modify to url to handle parameters with "/" 
eg

```
       $request_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];        
       $url         =  str_replace(LOCAL_PATH,"",$request_url);        
       $parameters   = explode("/",$url);

       if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']!='localhost')
       {
         $total = count($parameters)-1;
         unset($parameters[0]);        
         unset($parameters[1]);
         unset($parameters[2]); 
       }       
       $slipt = array_chunk($parameters, 2);
       $response = array();
       foreach($slipt as $val)
       {
          if( isset($val[1]) )
            $response[$val[0]] = $val[1];
       }         
      return $response;
```

This means that let we have url `"http://domaintest/controller/method/page/1";`

then here vaue of page parameter will be 1